# iOS Attachment download with Mailcore 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

I am working on a simple multimedia browser iOS app, where I login with my email account and I see JUST all my attachments.. I am using obj c and Mailcore2 framework.

I just got a problem. I can download my email and see them in the console, but I cant see the downloaded attachments..

This is my loademails method:

```
(void)loadEmails
{
 MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = (MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind)
(MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindStructure |
 MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindInternalDate | MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaderSubject |
 MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindFlags);

MCOIndexSet *uidSet = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1,UINT64_MAX)];//for all msgs

self.imapMessagesFetchOp = [self.imapSession fetchMessagesByUIDOperationWithFolder:@"INBOX"
                                                                       requestKind:requestKind
                                                                                uids:uidSet];




__weak MasterViewController *weakSelf = self;
[self.imapMessagesFetchOp start:^(NSError *error, NSArray *messages, MCOIndexSet *vanishedMessages) {
    MasterViewController *strongSelf = weakSelf;

NSLog(@"All emails fetched.");


strongSelf.messages = messages;

MCOIMAPMessage *msg = [messages lastObject];
MCOIMAPPart *part = [msg.attachments lastObject];

   MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation *mcop = [self.imapSession fetchMessageAttachmentOperationWithFolder:@"INBOX" uid:msg.uid partID:part.partID encoding:part.encoding];



    [mcop start:^(NSError *error, NSData *data) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"error:%@", error);
            return;
        }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *saveDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *attachmentPath = [saveDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:part.filename];
    [data writeToFile:attachmentPath atomically:YES];

    }];
[strongSelf rebuildSenderArray];
[strongSelf.tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"%lu emails fetched", (unsigned long)strongSelf.messages.count);

}];
}
```

Any suggestions for me? Thank you

Comment: use MCOMessageParser to parse the data you got from MCOIMAPFetchContentOperation.
And then, use parser->attachments();

Comment: But how Can I get just the attachment link? No other information? What I want is just login with email and see JUST the pictures.

Comment: data of the picture is available in the attachments.